# How to get the last record with a condition in Django

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get the last record of the table in Django with a condition.

Model: Rooms

| id | room | staff_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 103 | 1000 |
| 2 | 105 | 1000 |
| 3 | 107 | 1555 |

the staff (number 1000) has two records, but I want to get just the last record of him.

```
getStaffRecords = Rooms.objects.get(staff_id=1000)
staffRoom = getStaffRecords.room
```

and here I get an error, because I have more than one record.
Error: get() returned more than one Rooms-- it returned 2!

Anybody has a solution?

I tried to use the methode like this:

```
getStaffRecords = Rooms.objects.get(staff_id=1000).last()
staffRoom = getStaffRecords.room
```

but it didn't work, bcause in this case, "get" isn't recognized by Django.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Rooms.objects.filter(staff_id=1000).last()
```

That's because you can't use `last()` with the single object. The `get()` function returns single object.

Comment: It's working!
Great. I didn't know which type of objects return the get and filter.
Thanks.